# Elementary OS Jupiter Skin on Luna

Tags: elementary-os

I wanted to use Elementary OS. But I like the look of Jupiter much better than the look of the newer version Luna. But that version is no longer supported. So is it possible to get the old menu button and dock back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel in Luna, WingPanel, doesn't support much customization. You could install something like XFCE's panel, but then it wouldn't look and work the way it is intended to in Luna.

Regarding the dock, Plank: I created a Plank theme a while back that emulates the look of the dock in Jupiter. It's available [here](http://cassidyjames.deviantart.com/art/Jupiter-Redux-Formerly-Pantheon-theme-for-Plank-213303421).

Answer (score 0):

You can't make Luna exactly like Jupiter because Jupiter uses Gnome and Luna uses Pantheon as it desktop environment but you can customize the desktop to look like Jupiter or even osx.

here a artikel about desktop customization :  http://www.elementarynow.com/what-is-elementary-3/customize/

Comment: I just wanted to know how the dock skin is called

Comment: Sorry, I don't know